# Javascript function to load a CSS file in an iframe not hosted on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am using a service that creates a form that I load on my website within an iframe. I can put custom javascript to load inside the iframe when the form loads (I add the javascript in the form creator on the service's domain). I believe the function must use *either* **both** or **one** of the parameters "form" and "function". Like so:

```
function(field,form){
  code
}
```

*Is there a function I can call so that it will load a css file from a different domain that will apply to the content inside of the iframe?*

The domain in the iframe does load jQuery, but I'm not sure if it will allow me to call a jQuery function. If you give me a jQuery function, that would normally work inside of an iframe, I will test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you append a stylesheet link tag to the header, jQuery will handle creating and loading the stylesheet.

```
jQuery("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="URL_TO_CSS_FILE" />');
```

Note that this does depend on your ability to add JavaScript that runs inside the `iframe`.

Comment: Great this works! Thank you! I tested it, and it looks like I have the ability to run jQuery as well as Javascript. I can run it on button clicks as well as whenever someone loads the form. So this runs when someone loads the form.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could simply inject a CSS tag in the head section of the page :

As soon as the tag is inserted, it will load the CSS